# Some links broken after updating Wordpress version

Tags: php, permalinks, 404-error, updates

first post on here so go easy :) got a problem with a wordpress site (custom theme) http://expressduplication.co.uk which was built a few years ago by a company we are no longer able to get in touch with.

It was running an old version of wordpress 2.x.x (can't remember the exact version) and I have today updated to version 4.5.2.

Now whenever I click one of the links in the sub menu in the nav bar eg. Products > Special Offers, I receive a page cannot be found error and in the URL it is showing:

expressduplication.co.uk/SITE_HOME_URLspecial-offers

When it is supposed to be expressduplication.co.uk/special-offers

This works fine when inputted manually, just not through the links.

I notice "SITE_HOME_URL" getting inserted into links all over the site therefore breaking them, "THEME_PATH" is also getting inserted into links for some images therefore breaking them too. It seems like some request isn't being answered as it was in the old version of wordpress.

I have average experience and skills with Wordpress but this one has me beat.

Thanks for the help in advance :)

J

Comment: Does the error go away if you change themes?

Comment: No its the same on all themes which is concerning me. Jamie

Answer (score 0):

Search the theme source-code for `SITE_HOME_URL` and try replacing it with `WP_HOME` or with the result of `esc_url(home_url())`.  Locate `THEME_PATH` and replace it with the result of `get_theme_root()`.

EDIT: In the case of expressduplication.co.uk/SITE_HOME_URLspecial-offers there is probably a `wp_redirect()` or `wp_safe_redirect()` that doesnt work because of the undefined constant `SITE_HOME_URL`.

Comment: Thank you, just doing a backup and I will try this. Jamie